# textilize method not found on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redcloth

I have this line on my program

```
<dd><%= textilize @box.description %></dd>
```

but it gives that error
`undefined method 'textilize' for #<#<Class:0x000000038145e0>:0x00000003fc1428>`,I have installed RedCloth 4.2.9 but it is still not working.

Comment: Did you restart your dev server after gem installation?

Comment: I didn't (i'am totally beginner of rails),now works ,thanks